# String equality issue in C#

Tags: c#, string, string-comparison

I have the following if-else statement in a C# method (which returns a JSON object).
The else statement executes even though the condition for the if statement (language == "en") is true.
Why is this? The method is called by the following line(s) of code in another file:

```
Ux.locale.Manager.setConfig({
        ajaxConfig : {
            method : 'GET'
        },
        language   : 'en',
        tpl        : 'getLocale.castle?language={locale}',
        type       : 'ajax'
    });
```

The `language` value is combined with the `tpl` value to produce the URL that calls the method (in my case: `getLocale.castle?language=en`).

```
    [return: JSONReturnBinder]
     public Locale GetLocale(string language)
     {
        if (language == "en")
        {
           Locale englishLang = new Locale();
           englishLang.region.center.title = "Center Region";
           englishLang.region.east.title = "East Region - Form";
           englishLang.buttons.save = "Save";
           englishLang.fields.labels.firstName = "First Name";
           englishLang.fields.labels.lastName = "Last Name";
           englishLang.fields.labels.chooseLocale = "Choose Your Locale";       
           return englishLang;
       } else {
            Locale frenchLang = new Locale();
            frenchLang.region.center.title = "Region Centre";
            frenchLang.region.east.title = "Region Est - Formulaire";
            frenchLang.buttons.save = "Enregistrer";
            frenchLang.fields.labels.firstName = "Prenom";
            frenchLang.fields.labels.lastName = "Nom";
            frenchLang.fields.labels.chooseLocale = "Choisissez vos paramètres régionaux";
            return frenchLang; 
       }
}
```

I have tried using `if (language.Equals("en"))` but even then the else statement executes and not the if statement.

Comment: Are you sure that the value of `language` inside c# code is `"en"`?

Comment: And `language` is guaranteed to be `"en"`? I mean, you **double-checked** this?

Comment: Are you 100% sure this is the correct way of passing that argument to the method? Can you set a breakpoint inside the method to verify that it isn't null?

Comment: I do recommend to add verbose logging to the GetLocale method

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(language == "en");`

Comment: I just checked what the value is of `language` and its `"System.String[]"` not `"en"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the variable `language` was used twice (once in `language` property in the line `language : 'en'` and a second time in the line `tpl: 'getLocale.castle?language={locale}'`. This caused confusion when the `language` parameter was passed to the getLocale method (the correct `language` parameter was not being passed). When I changed the name of the `language` parameter, the problem was solved and the if-statement was executed.

Answer (score 1):

> The else statement executes even though the condition for the if statement (language == "en") is true. Why is this?

Most likely cause? `language` **does not** equal *"en"*. Make sure you don't have any extra whitespace in your variable (common pitfall and can sometimes be unapparent to the human eye when inspecting the debugger) and check the casing is correct.

For example, try

```
language.Trim().ToLower() == "en"
```

and chances are your problem will dissappear.